# Symfony3 service not found by twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've got the following problem. I've got a service. And I want to use that service in every TWIG template. But it does not find my service.

I get the following error:

```
ServiceNotFoundException in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 58:
The service "twig" has a dependency on a non-existent service "appbundle\service\categoryhandler".
```

Notice that the service is not camelcased, while it is camelcased in my config.yml.

Here's my config.yml part

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    globals:
        categories: '@AppBundle\Service\CategoryHandler'
```

I already added PHP templating engine ([found this 'solution' while googling my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843765/symfony-2-servicenotfoundexception-non-existent-service-templating-engine-php#33844323)).

```
templating:
        engines: ['twig', 'php']
```

[**I've followed this documentation of Symfony**](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html)

Comment: Where did you define the service `@AppBundle\Service\CategoryHandler`?

Comment: @dbrumann Nowhere. Where do I need to define it then?

Comment: e.g. in your config.yml under `services:` or in a services.yml that is imported into the config.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it cannot find your CategoryHandler service.

Has it been registered? Or, has auto loading been enabled?
http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container

Comment: Thanks that was it. Just found it out myself because of dbrumann told me in the comments. Thanks tho